# Como generar un 'limit_choices' con los 'id' de una tabla seleccionada previamente en '/admin'

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

Estoy utilizando `GenericForeigKey` para relacionar varios modelos a uno solo, tengo el siguiente código:

```
class IPuertoOptico(models.Model):
    nomenclatura = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    limit = models.Q(app_label='infrastructure', model='itarjeta') |  \
        models.Q(app_label='infrastructure', model='iequipo')

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ContentType,
        limit_choices_to=limit,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    autor = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    fecha_hora_alta = models.DateTimeField(
    null=True, blank=True, default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Puertos Opticos "

    def __str__(self):
            return '%s' % (self.nomenclatura)
```

En el `admin.py` tengo lo siguiente:

```
class IPuertoOpticoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = [f.name for f in IPuertoOptico._meta.fields]
    exclude = ('autor', 'fecha_hora_alta',)

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.autor = request.user
        obj.save()
admin.site.register(IPuertoOptico, IPuertoOpticoAdmin)
```

El problema es que en el `/admin` para poner un valor en `object_id` tengo que estar consultando los `id` existentes en el objeto previamente seleccionado en `content_type`

Lo que quiero hacer es poner un `limit_choices_to` en el campo `object_id` que se auto rellene con los id del objeto seleccionado previamente en el campo `content_type`.

Alguien me puede ayudar por favor.

Comment: Rocke, puedes compartir una captura de pantalla del formulario que hablas? O el admin.py.

Comment: Listo Fermin, ya agregue el admin.py, Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si puedes cambiar de Tema del admin y puedes utilizar Django Grapelli es posible que te funcione. Django Grapelli te permite usar 'autocomplete_lookup_fields' en el admin. Puedes ver un ejemplo aca:

https://axiacore.com/blog/how-use-genericforeignkey-django/

En lo personal yo edite el formulario admin de mi modelo y cree un código javascript que capturaba el modelo seleccionado (contentype) y luego pedía el listado de objetos a un web service (un view que devuelve un JSON). Este objeto JSON lo cargaba en un SELECT y cuando el usuario selecciona un objeto en particular, un evento escribía el id al campo de object_id.

En resumen no hay una configuración inmediata que te permita hacer esto.

Comment: Fermin, Gracias por tu valioso comentario, Grapelli fue la única opción que encontré para realizar esto de la forma mas simple, pero en lo personal también prefiero modificar el formulario, es un camino mas laborioso pero mas óptimo al final. Saludos